# High resolution monitor extended with a lower resolution monitor scaling issues

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, resolution

I've got a laptop with a UHD display connected via a USB3 dock to a normal monitor with Full HD. This runs Windows 10 professional.

I seem to have a bit of a problem between the scaling of items between the two monitors. Sometimes (but not all the time), icons and displays will get confused as to what monitor it's running on.

To explain this, desktop icons on the FHD display sometimes are scaled at 200%, and other times the icons the UHD display display at 100%. Additionally, certain windows and texts are blurry, almost like they are being scaled up/down and then reduce/enlarged to properly match the display.

I've also attached an image of what sometimes happens when moving between monitors. In this case, I'm moving a window from the UHD display to to the FHD display, and during the time when it crosses both windows, it appears on the larger of the two monitors at 200%, and remains this way until the window has been completely enclosed by the FHD monitor (at which point scales down to 100%).

Does anyone have any suggestions about how to fix this?

[image: Scaling bug]

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Nvidia or AMD graphics card, you can use the DSR (dynamic super resolution; nvidia) or VSR (virtual super resolution; amd) option to allow your smaller monitor to run at the same resolution as your bigger one and then get downscaled to fit the screen, this works surprisingly well but only for extended displays (if you try to duplicate the displays this option is disabled) so for example for a UHD display and FHD display you would have to enable DSR 4x on the FHD display, then go to the screen resolution settings and set the FHD screen to UHD resolution in order for this to work, the computer will think you have 2 UHD screens now and everything should scale the same across the displays.

Intel iGPUs do not have this feature yet. This will cause a performance loss, but will also actually increase the image quality of your smaller display in return so it's a somewhat ideal solution.

AMD and Nvidia have also (as of this writing) not yet implemented support for this feature in Linux, but I may look into a way to do this on Linux later and update this post if I remember.